# How can I make variables available in the view when I do redirect_to :back?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller

I can just make a `@variable` in a regular controller action, and it will be available in the view. But when I do `redirect_to :back`, the variables are no longer available. How do I pass them along, so they can be displayed in the view?

**More Information**:
The user submits something in a form (fromt the "show" page), and it gets passed to the "submit" action. The text gets processed to a result. I then want to return two texts to the original page - the submission itself and the result.

Controller:

```
def show     
//show submission and results if they exist
end

def submit
//do stuff with submission and return submission and results back
redirect_to :back
end
```

Comment: Just pass them along as a session variable.

Comment: This is a bad advice. As u rule of thumb you shouldn't use session. Maybe user29358 can explain what exactly is he trying to do so we can figure out some good solution.

Comment: @cthulhu, it looks like it will work. I added more info in case there's a better way.

Comment: It 'will work', but is is not a good design. It fails - for example - when you start using your app in two browser tabs. I will elaborate more soon.

Comment: You are approaching the problem from wrong direction. You shouldn't redirect to ':back' at all. Just redirect to a proper controller action, with all attributes needed in request parameters.

Comment: @cthulhu, i started doing that, but now I think it doesn't make sense to pass all that info in the URL when it could just be kept in the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you just want a single value you'd do something like:

```
session[:name] = @variable.name
```

If you want the whole object later, you'd do something like:

```
session[:variable_id] = @variable.id
```

then

```
@variable = Variable.find(session[:variable_id])
```

Cheers!